# External Bigquery hive partition table created for dataset but not able to view the column with partition key

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset, bq

I have created a terraform script for creating a dataset and External table in Bigquery. Below is the terraform script

```
  1 resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "bigquery" {
  2   dataset_id                  = "${var.biqquery_dataset_id}"
  3   friendly_name               = "${var.friendly_name}"
  4   description                 = "This is a test description"
  5   location                    = "${var.location}"
  6   project                     = "${var.project}"  
  7   default_table_expiration_ms = 3600000
  8 
  9   labels = {
 10     env = "default"
 11   }
 12 }
 13 
 14 resource "google_bigquery_table" "bigquery_sheet" {
 15   dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.bigquery.dataset_id
 16   table_id   = "${var.bigquery_table_id}"
 17   project                     = "${var.project}"
 18 
 19  schema = <<EOF
 20 [
 21   {
 22     "name": "ip",
 23     "type": "STRING",
 24     "mode": "NULLABLE",
 25     "description": "The Permalink"
 26   },
 27 
 28   {
 29     "name": "fraudType",
 30     "type": "STRING",
 31     "mode": "NULLABLE",
 32     "description": "The Permalink"
 33   },
 34 
 35   {
 36     "name": "probability",
 37     "type": "FLOAT",
 38     "mode": "NULLABLE",
 39     "description": "State where the head office is located"
 40   }
 41 
 42 ]
 43 EOF
 44 
 45   external_data_configuration {
 46     autodetect    = false
 47     source_format = "${var.source_format}"
 48 
 49  csv_options {
 50     quote = ""
 51     allow_jagged_rows = "false"
 52     skip_leading_rows = "0"
 53 
 54 }
 55  hive_partitioning_options {
 56     mode              = "AUTO"
 57     source_uri_prefix = "gs://xxxx/file/"
 58  }
 59  ignore_unknown_values = "false"
 60     source_uris = [
 61       "gs://xxxx/file/*",
 62     ]
 63   }
 64 }
```

I am able to create the hive partition external table under a dataset, it's missing to create partition key as a column. But when I create from the google cloud console with the same schema, I am able to view the partition key column in the table details section correctly.

The **terraform scripts missing** the partition key column when it's creating the table.

I am not sure what else is missing on the scripts.

Comment: What do you mean by the fourth column? Can you be more specific? Maybe by showing exactly what do you see when creating the table manually and by using terraform

Comment: Please share the commands used to create the create the table manually, also the command used to  get the schema information and  a screenshot could be useful to figure out what is happen.

Comment: Updated the question. Let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: It's strange , in case of an issue with an unsupported partition the gcloud command must failed too; nevertheless, the table is created without issues, I think that Terraform uses the BigQuery REST API to create the table, I suggest you make a test with the REST API by your own instead of the gcloud command to validate if it works too.

Answer (score 0):

The `schema` attribute needs to be in the `external_data_configuration` block and not the top level `google_bigquery_table` block.

I have no idea why both positions are valid but only one honours the partitioning field.